# when I type python in powershell or cmd, it opens microsoft store instead of starting python shell. How to fix this?

Tags: python, powershell, cmd

I have already added python to path and disabled app installer python.exe and python3.exe from app execution aliases, but the problem persists. what shall I do to fix this?

Comment: Please check the Path you defined in Environment variable 'Path' might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to Python.org's documentation page [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html), the two primary ways of installing Python on Windows is by using the full installer found on their website or installing via the Microsoft Store package. The Microsoft Store package of Python has been known to introduce bugs that are not found in the full install of Python. Microsoft has a [FAQ page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/faqs#why-does-running-pythonexe-open-the-microsoft-store) about running Python on Windows where they specifically mention the issue you are facing. Per Microsoft,

> To help new users find a good installation of Python, we added a
> shortcut to Windows that will take you directly to the latest version
> of the community's package published in the Microsoft Store.
>
> If you install Python using the installers from python.org and select
> the "add to PATH" option, the new python command will take priority
> over the shortcut.

Having run into plenty of issues with the Microsoft Store package of Python myself, my (and Microsoft's) recommendation would be to uninstall the Microsoft Store version of Python from your PC and install the official Python package and to make sure to check the "Add to PATH" option when doing so. The link to the official package can be found [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).